# Java source to RDF conversion

Tags: semantic-web

Is there a way to convert java source directly to equivalent RDF? I am aware of manually creating and java object to RDF/OWL object mapping by Jena API, but I need the automation of the mapping of java source code to RDF/OWL object. Is there any available tool for that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You might check out [Empire](https://github.com/mhgrove/Empire), which is integration between JPA and SPARQL letting you build an application around standard POJOs which are stored in an RDF triplestore.  It handles round-tripping between RDF and Java for you and abstracts most of the details of RDF -- though some SPARQL knowledge is ideal.